# Android 6.0 USB OTG - How to bypass Android Storage Access Framework w/ root

Tags: android, usb-otg

I am trying to read/write directly to a usb otg flash drive.
Through the Android Storage Access Framework it is possible but I need a programmatical way that does not require user interaction.

Since I got root on the device, I tried a simple R/W to the typical usb-otg locations.

```
/storage/UsbDriveA (all Samsung devices)
/storage/USBstorage1 (LG G4, V10, G3, G2, other LG devices)
/storage/usbdisk (Moto Maxx, Turbo 2, Moto X Pure, other Motorola devices)
/storage/usbotg (Sony Xperia devices, Lenovo Tabs)
/storage/UDiskA (Oppo devices)
/storage/usb-storage (Acer Iconia Tabs)
/storage/usbcard (Dell Venue -- Vanilla Android 4.3 tablet)
/storage/usb (HTC One M7, and some Vanilla Android devices)
```

The Uri provided by the Android SAF

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/B12Q130%3ASAMPLE
```

And the location provided by TWRP recovery

```
/storage/usb-otg
```

Interestingly enough, even with an inner terminal and su I can't directly access the USB files.
Although it is only possible so far with the Android SAF.

Could anybody here please point me in the right direction?
Thanks